# PHP function to get recursive path keys with path

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Given an array, I would like a flattened version of the array keys.  Each array key would need the 'path' of the array, to that point, appended with an underscore.

An example explains this best.

```
$arr = array("location"=>0,"details"=>array("width"=>0,"height"=>0,"level"=>array("three"=>0)));

function answer($arr) {....}
```

the answer function would return this:

```
array("location","details_width","details_height","details_level_three");
```

UPDATE:

Here is the work in progress. It will accept an array and return the array keys, but with no depth:

```
function recursive_keys($input)
{
    $output = array_keys($input);
    foreach($input as $sub){
        if(is_array($sub)){
            $output = array_merge($output, recursive_keys($sub));
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I have a set of functions that can successfully traverse a multidimensional array, and return all the array keys .  But I don't know how to append the current 'path' as I am traversing the array.

Comment: well show your unsuccessffull attempts

Comment: original comment has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function recursive_keys(array $array, array $path = array()) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $currentPath = array_merge($path, array($key));
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, recursive_keys($val, $currentPath));
        } else {
            $result[] = join('_', $currentPath);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Demo here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/WQ3UYI

Comment: Excellent, this is what I need!  To your code, I added if(!is_array($val)) right before the if(!is_array($val)) line as I dont' want to add a key if it's value is an array.

Comment: I use `if (is_array($val) && $val)` instead of `if (is_array($val))` to get it work in my case

Comment: @deceze this demo link has died.  This answer could also use some explanation.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
$results = array();
foreach ($ritit as $leafValue) {
    $path = array();
    foreach (range(0, $ritit->getDepth()) as $depth) {
        $path[] = $ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->key();
    }
    $results[] = join('_', $path);
}
```

Comment: +1 For the idea, anyway if you are dealing with empty arrays (as I did) this solution is not complete because the RecursiveArrayIterator cannot recognize the 'leaves'. To make it work with leaves array that are empty you can use a class similar to this: 
`class RecursiveArrayOnlyIterator extends RecursiveArrayIterator {
    public function hasChildren() {
        return is_array($this->current()) && (count($this->current())>0);
    }
}`
Reference: [php.net](http://it1.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php)

Comment: @AntonioE. you could also just use the `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST` arg for the RecursiveIteratorIterator constructor(then it will visit all nodes, not just leaves). But, you will get many partial, less than full paths as a result.