# Extract "path" from array

Tags: php, arrays, api

I'm working on documenting an API, so I am parsing example XML/JSOn output and need to find all the named keys to add definitions. So, I have an array like this:

```
$array = [
  "user" => [
    "name" => "John",
    "email" => "email@email.com",
    "products" => [
      0 => "product A",
      1 => "product B"
    ],
    "files" => [
      "logo" => "/path/logo.jpg",
      "profile" => "/path/profile.jpg"
    ]
  ],
  "offer" => [
    0 => "My offer"
  ]
];
```

And I want to extract all the keys from the array, no matter its depth, and get an output akin to:

```
$keys = [
  0 => ["user"],
  1 => ["user", "name"],
  2 => ["user", "email"],
  3 => ["user", "products"],
  4 => ["user", "files"],
  5 => ["user", "files", "logo"],
  6 => ["user", "files", "profile"],
  7 => ["offer"]
];
```

Note that keys that are numeric are ignored, only named keys are included in the hierarchy. I have googled and tried to find something that does this, but I've come up blank. I have tried some function chaining but I just can't wrap my head around the loops and returns correctly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: " I have tried some function chaining", please show us your attempt!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP function to get recursive path keys with path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392619/php-function-to-get-recursive-path-keys-with-path)

Comment: @0stone0 Not really, it ignores the first level "user" and "product" and includes numerical keys, I'll see if I canm tweak it. It's very similar to my own efforts though

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with help of @0stone0 I was directed to a Stackoverflow answer that led me right, this is the end function:

```
function definitionTree(array $array): array{
    $tree = function($siblings, $path) use (&$tree) {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($siblings as $key => $val) {
            $currentPath = is_numeric($key) ? $path : array_merge($path, [$key]);
            if (is_array($val)) {
                if (!is_numeric($key)) $result[] = join(' / ', $currentPath);
                $result = array_merge($result, $tree($val, $currentPath));
            } else {
                $result[] = join(' / ', $currentPath);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    };
    $paths = $tree($array, []);
    return array_unique($paths);
}
```

Which returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => user
    [1] => user / name
    [2] => user / email
    [3] => user / products
    [6] => user / files
    [7] => user / files / logo
    [8] => user / files / profile
    [9] => offer
)
```