# Get all path indexes while recursively searching for a value in a multidimensional array of indeterminant depth

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, iterator

I have N Level Array like

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => 67941,
        'parent_id' => 0,
        'name' => 'Requirement',
        'children' => [
            [
                'id' => 67942,
                'parent_id' => 67941,
                'name' => 'Sub Requirement',
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'id' => 67943,
                        'parent_id' => 67942,
                        'name' => 'Sub Sub Requirement',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    //...
];
```

I want to search for **67943** -- which is at the 3rd indexed level (5th level actually) of the array. I can use `array_walk_recursive()` to find if the value exists or not, but I need to collect the full path of indexes which lead to the value e.g. `$array[0][0][0]['id']`.

I can't hardcode the levels, I need a solution which can work on an array with upwards of 100 levels.

Comment: Create a recursive function, if key 'children' exist call the function recursively and every time just check if the id equals what you are looking for

Comment: When you say 'full trail' do you mean a reference to the array that contains id = 67943?  Or are you looking for a string representation of the 'path' through the various arrays that gets you to that value?  (Those are two quite different results)

Comment: Also, if you are having that many levels deep, then a recursive function may not be the best answer, as you will end up filling your stack.  A breadth-first traversal might be more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a lot of experience with the RecursiveIteratorIterator class or its cousins, but I was able to modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8393134/2943403) to suit your conditional requirements.

While traversing the array, if the key is "children" don't cache the key.

If the value is the search value, then capture the current path of keys and break the loop.

I don't understand why you'd like a return value of `$array[0][0][0]['id']`, so I'll just return a flat array containing the keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PPXul))

```
$needle = 67943;

$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
$result = null;
foreach ($ritit as $leafValue) {
    $path = [];
    foreach (range(0, $ritit->getDepth()) as $depth) {
        $obj = $ritit->getSubIterator($depth);
        $key = $obj->key();
        if ($key !== 'children') {
            $path[] = $key;
        }
        if ($obj->current() === $needle) {
            $result = $path;
            break 2;
        }

    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 0,
  2 => 0,
  3 => 'id',
)
```